# How to use "eventually" with "Specs2RouteTest"

Tags: scala, scalatest, spec2, spray-test

There are two specs here. First is not passing because `eventually` in `check` will not cause whole route rerun but this is the way I would prefer to follow. The second spec is the best solution I found (and prove that it is doable ;) ) but it contains some boilerplate like additional function which in real life will have to return rather tuple than single thing and it is inconsistent with spray-tests syntax design to test routs.

So question is:
**How to use `eventually` with spray-tests to be as close as possible to syntax from first spec.**

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import spray.routing.Directives
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._
import HttpCharsets._
import spray.testkit.Specs2RouteTest

class EventuallyAndRouts extends Specification with Directives with Specs2RouteTest {

    var i = 0
    def incAndGet = {
        i = i + 1
        println(s"This is i = $i")
        s"$i"
    }

    "The testing infrastructure should support an eventually matcher" >> {
        "but it is not working inside a check as I need :( (and this will fail)" in {
            i = 0
            Get() ~> complete(incAndGet) ~> check {
                body must eventually(7, 20 millis)(be_===(HttpEntity(ContentType(`text/plain`, `UTF-8`), "5")))
            }
        }
        "so I got workaround :/ (and this is passing)" in {
            i = 0
            def requestResult = Get() ~> complete(incAndGet) ~> check {
                body
            }
            requestResult must eventually(7, 20 millis)(be_===(HttpEntity(ContentType(`text/plain`, `UTF-8`), "5")))
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventually` is used to evaluate repeatedly a value that is changing. So it either has to be a `var`, a `def` or a byname parameter.

The best way around that is probably for you to implement a `checkEventually(times, delay)` method that will incorporate the `eventually` call. Something like that:

```
implicit class Checked(request: =>Request) {
  def checkEventually[R : AsResult](times: Int, delay: Duration, matcher: Matcher[RequestResult])(body: =>Unit)( = {
    val requestResult = result ~> check(body)
    requestResult must eventually(times, delay)(matcher)
  }
}
```

Comment: I've wrote something similar basing on your suggestion (I've omitted implicit and class declaration and added method to spec class) and I've noticed that calling: result ~> check(body) will not cause route rerun. It is just checking few times same result.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spray's routing but yes you need to invoke a function that will run the request again. Note that I'm using a byname parameter in the implicit class to that effect. Maybe you should ask on the spray mailing-list if there is one?